# Oracle timestamp with timezone : replace date portion to current date

Tags: sql, database, date, timestamp, oracle12c

I have a oracle table for maintaining cutoff time. here we are storing cutoff time for various securities.. currently we are defaulting date portion of cutoff to 1st Jan 1970. The requirement is to replace this date portion with current date without changing time and timezone portion of cutoff.

Comment: Can you give some sample rows and the expected output clearly.

Comment: @Utsav cutoff column(timestamp with timezone datatype) data is like this "1970-01-01 18:00:00 -5:00".

Expected output is "2017-06-03 18:00:09 -5:00" i.e. todays date with the timestamp part of cutoff column

Comment: There is a logical problem with this request... "date" is not well defined. Which date should be used? The date "right this moment" is June 6, 2017, in the U.S. and Europe, but it is June 7, 2017, in Japan and Australia. Since you are using timestamps WITH TIME ZONE, which are offset from UTC, it would make sense to extract the current date FROM UTC, not from SYSDATE and similar.

Answer (score 0):

You could calculate the number of days between today and 1970-01-01, and then add that as a day-to-second interval to your cutoff timestamp value:

```
create table my_table (cutoff timestamp with time zone);

insert into my_table values (timestamp '1970-01-01 18:00:00 -5:00');

select cutoff + numtodsinterval(trunc(sysdate) - date '1970-01-01', 'DAY') as adjusted
from my_table;

ADJUSTED                           
-----------------------------------
05-JUN-17 18.00.00.000000000 -05:00
```

or if you prefer, you can generate an interval directly (as @mathguy pointed out):

```
select cutoff + (trunc(sysdate) - timestamp '1970-01-01 00:00:00') as adjusted
from my_table;

ADJUSTED                 
-------------------------
06-JUN-17 18:00:00 -05:00
```

The -05:00 time zone offset ignores daylight savings time, of course, but that seems to be what you intended.

Comment: The idea is correct, but why truncate `SYSDATE` and subtract a date, only to apply `NUMTODSINTERVAL` to the result? Better: truncate `SYSTIMESTAMP` and subtract a timestamp literal; the result can be added directly to `CUTOFF`.

Comment: Also see my note to the OP asking for clarification... timestamps with time zone are offset from UTC, so it seems unnatural to use the "current date" of the user's system (as shown in `SYSDATE` or `SYSTIMESTAMP`); rather, that should be converted to UTC first, and only then truncate. Best if the OP confirms, since this is not a "coding" issue, it is a "problem specification" issue.

Comment: @mathguy - not sure it makes much difference, but OK. `trunc(systimestamp)` still gives you a date (so not much benefit of that over `sysdate`?), but subtracting a timestamp from that does still give an interval. Added a version doing that. I thought the first was a bit more explicit, but either requires knowing how datetime/interval arithmetic works, which doesn't seem to be a given for a lot of people *8-)

Comment: @mathguy - or indeed `current_date` or `current_timestamp`, as the distinction between system and session time wasn't provided either. But anyway, yes, agree basing on UTC makes sense.

Comment: err... It never even crossed my mind to test, or to check the documentation. Obviously you are right and `TRUNC` converts a timestamp to a date. That makes no sense to me - why not to a timestamp? Obviously you are correct (I just tested and I also found the specific language about this in the documentation), it's just odd.

Comment: No idea, guess when they added the timestamp data types they forgot or didn't bother to (or couldn't for some reason) overload that function. The passed-in timestamp is cast to date before the function even sees it, I think, so the function itself doesn't convert it.. maybe. Same for [`round()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions255.htm#SQLRF52058) too. Also notice that neither accepts SS or any timestamp-specific format elements.